# Union of sets which are not grouped together as a set

Tags: set-theory, axioms

I am reading Halmos set theory, by substitution axiom we can form a union of sets which are constructed using the sentence the form s(a,b). 
My question is, lets say for each natural number I have set $A_n$, is it possible to take union of these sets?

Edit: $A_n$'s are not indexed

Comment: Yes, the axiom of union allows such a union.

Comment: Does Halmos talk about the axiom of replacement?

Comment: @AsafKaragila No, but the the substitution axioms helps us take the needed union to form the set containing $\omega, \omega^+, (\omega^+)^+$

Comment: @HanulJeon $A_n$ are not indexed, just I'm using such notation

Comment: @Saravanan Sorry, I could not understand what you have meant. Could you clarify it?

Comment: @HanulJeon We can take use axiom of union only if we have a set containing ${A_1, A_2,...}$ right? Here I only know the existence of $A_1, A_2,...$

Comment: @Saravanan I think your assertion only makes sense when you specify some explicit description of $A_i$. As far as I understand, we have $A_n$ for each $n$, but it seems make sense only when we have a function $f$ such that $f(n)=A_n$ for all $n$. Is there any particular situation have you bear in mind?

Comment: @HanulJeon I can have sets $\{0\}, \{0^+\}, \{(0^+)^+\},...$ but to take union of these axiom of union is not enough, so we have axiom infinity. Also, we have a substitution axiom to take union of sets certain kind of sets, I am thinking of sets which can't be grouped by even substation axiom, i don't have any example of such a group of sets

Comment: @AsafKaragila Why did you ask about the axiom of replacement?

Comment: Because it would be useful here...

Comment: @AsafKaragila But, in my question $A_n$'s kind of arbitrary, I just know their existence nothing more, yeah understood the index is misleading

Comment: If you have a set, for each $n$, then by Replacement, $\{A_n\mid n<\omega\}$ is a set. Nobody asked you to somehow specify each $A_n$. The question you need to ask *yourself* is what do you mean by "for each natural number I have a set $A_n$".

Comment: @AsafKaragila "for each natural number I have a set $A_n$" means $(1, A_1), (2, A_2), (3, A_3)$... exhaust every $A_n$ but no function which binds $(n, A_n)$, I have no way of collecting all together, I have no way to differentiate  $(n, A_m)$ from $(k, A_k)$, am I making any sense? In my understanding to apply Replacement I should have some formula to associate $n$ and $A_n$ am I right?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Or I am arbitrarily picking elements from $\omega$ and I want a set containing all those, is such a thing possible?

Comment: No, you're not making much sense here. Of course you can differ between $(n,A_n)$ and $(k,A_k)$. The sets $n$ and $k$ are different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102787/discussion-between-saravanan-and-asaf-karagila).

Comment: Sorry, I rather not use the chat if it's not necessary.